# In Gulp how do you negate multiple items e.g. ignore a file and a directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

In Gulp how do you negate multiple items e.g. ignore a file and a directory?

I want to combine the following:

```
gulp.src(['./**/*.{css,js,gif,png,php,eot,svg,ttf,woff}', '!./src/**/*'])

gulp.src(['./**/*.{css,js,gif,png,php,eot,svg,ttf,woff}', '!./gulpfile.js'])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add them on to your list:

```js
gulp.src(['./**/*.{css,js,gif,png,php,eot,svg,ttf,woff}',
          '!./src/**/*',
          '!./gulpfile.js'])
```

You can have as many items in your glob list as you want.